# How should blade grammar be applied to jquery when requested by Laravel Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am writing a code to delete records of results after passing the foreach statement, but I wonder how to apply blade grammar to jery.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                        @if(Auth::check() && $translationRecords)
                            @foreach($translationRecords as $translationRecord)                            
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="recodeValue{{ $translationRecord->id }}" style="display:none">{{ $translationRecord->id }}</td>

                                    <td>{{ $translationRecord->korean }}</td>

                                    <td>{{ $translationRecord->japanese }}</td>

                                    <td><button id="recodeRemoveBtn{{ $translationRecord->id }}" type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right">삭제</button></td>

                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif    
                    </table>
```

ajax

```
$("#recodeRemoveBtn{{ $translationRecord->id }}").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{route('translation.recode.delete')}}',
        type: 'post',
        data: {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                'id': $('#recodeValue{{ $translationRecord->id }}').val(),
            },
        success: function (data) {
            alery(data)

        }, error: function () {
            alert("error!!!!");
        }
    });
});
```

Route

```
Route::post('translation/delete', 'Home\TranslationController@recodeDelete')->name('translation.recode.delete')->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score 0):

at the end of the blade you have to put the route of your js archive. So the `click(function()` is gonna be calling.

Comment: <script src="js/example.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

You can solve this with blade magic. Just loop through the translationRecords the same way you did to create the table rows.

```
@foreach($translationRecords as $translationRecord)                            
   ... your ajax snippet repeated for each record ...
@endforeach
```

**Option 2**

But the simpler way would be to do inject the record's ID into the jQuery click event. There are dozens of ways to approach this option. The solution here uses [data-attributes](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

First add a class and the record's ID to the button with a data attribute.

```
<td>
    <button 
         id="recodeValue{{ $translationRecord->id }}"
         type="button" 
         class="btn btn-danger float-right recodeRemoveBtn"
         data-translation-record-id="{{ $translationRecord->id }}
    >
        삭제
    </button>
</td>
```

Second, adjust the jQuery to apply to *any* click event on a button with class "recodeRemoveBtn"

```
$("button.recodeRemoveBtn").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{route('translation.recode.delete')}}',
        type: 'post',
        data: {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                'id': $(this).data("translation-record-id"),
            },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)

        }, error: function () {
            alert("error!!!!");
        }
    });
});
```